# Tangency between two circumcircles of triangles stemming from an acute triangle (IMO 2015)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, plane-geometry

I'm posting here the question because I want to see a nice synthetic solution (not using complex numbers or inversive geometry) for the 3rd problem from IMO 2015.
The problem is as follows:

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with $AB>AC$. Let $\Gamma$ be its circumcircle, $H$ its orthocenter, and $F$ the foot of the altitude from $A$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Let $Q$ be the point on $\Gamma$ such that $\angle HQA=90^{\circ}$ and let $K$ be the point on $\Gamma$ such that $\angle HKQ=90^{\circ}$. Assume that the points $A,B,C,K$ and $Q$ are all different and lie on $\Gamma$ in this order.
>
> Prove that the circumcircles of triangles $KQH$ and $FKM$ are tangent to each other.

I checked the [post from AoPS](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1112748p5079655) but I was not satisfied. I solved the problem using complex numbers and I want to see (if possible) a full synthetic solution and the motivation using some points or constructions.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! It's usually recommended to include your own work in your question so we can see where you got lost, and better help you.

Comment: The thing is I didn't get lost. I just want to see a nice solution to this problem (if someone wants to show me - I appreciate it!)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Both days of the competition ended more than one day ago, and [the problems are available from the IMO2015 website](http://www.imo2015.org/files/2015-eng.pdf).